# are there any core differences in the various Git binaries available for OSX?

Tags: macos, git, github

When you "Install Command Line Tools" from the Github.app, you get symlink'd Git binaries pointing inside the Github.app, like so:

```
/usr/local/bin/git -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/bin/git
$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
```

Meanwhile OSX/Xcode has it's own flavor:

```
$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)
```

And of course the official distro:

```
/usr/local/git/bin/git --version
git version 1.8.3.2
```

Is there any appreciable difference in these binaries (beyond the point versions?). I just want the fastest version for a large repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release notes:

https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.2.txt
https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.1.txt
https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.12.4.txt

And in particular:

https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.0.txt

Which has the 'new since 1.7.12' you probably care about.

But why not use the most recent one?

Comment: I was primarily curious if the Github or Apple binaries were any different than the official one, I suppose not.